# Expresión regular para hora en formato hh:mm:ss

Tags: php, regex

Necesito que las horas solo puedan ser de 1 a 24, y los minutos y segundos de 1 a 60. Al ponerle la restricción [0-24] en horas y [0-60] en minutos y segundos, me da error

De momento mi código es el siguiente:

```
$hora = "15:30:12";
if(preg_match("/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/", $hora, $partes)){
    echo "<p>La hora completa es " . $partes[0] . "</p>";
    echo "<p> Hora " . $partes[1] . "</p>";
    echo "<p> Minutos " . $partes[2] . "</p>";
    echo "<p> Segundos " . $partes[3] . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Formato de fecha no válido</p>";
}
```

Comment: Por favor, cuando preguntes, comparte el código que te da error y qué error te da. El mensaje de error completo. No sabemos si el problema de tus modificaciones sea de sintaxis y al no mostrar cómo lo intentaste, no podemos decirte por qué falló. Para que recibas respuestas rápidamente y de pronto validar mejor lo que intentas, puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir todo esto

Comment: Si, seguramente sea de sintaxis, pues mi respuesta no varia demasiado de su descripción que decia haber probado.

Comment: ¿Necesitas validar horas en formato `hh:mm:ss`? En la parte que corresponde solo a la hora ¿es valido poner `01` y `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que al querer usar REGEX para esto estés intentando reinventar la rueda.

PHP dispone de una clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) a cuyo constructor le puedes pasar una fecha y/u hora válidas. Esa clase te creará un objeto `DateTime` y puedes usar sus métodos para lo que necesites. En este caso, mediante `format` puedes mostrar cualquier parte del objeto que te interese. [Aquí puedes ver](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) todas las posibilidades de formato que puedes usar con objetos `DateTime`.

Peroooo, ¿cómo manejo el `else`, el supuesto formato no válido? Muy simple, si el formato que le pases al constructor de `DateTime` no es válido, se levantará una excepción, la cual puedes capturar y desde dentro emitir un mensaje de error personalizado. Dicho de otro modo, sustituirías el `if ... else` por un `try ... catch`.

Veamos un ejemplo de tu código, mucho más simple y sabiendo que `$mTime` aquí será un objeto, y podrás usarlo para lo que quiera, desde cosas tan simples como mostrarlo en un determinado formato, hasta cosas más complejas como dividirlo en intervalos, calculares períodos, modificarlo, etc.

```
$hora = "15:30:12";

try 
{
    $mTime=new DateTime($hora);
    printf("<p> Hora %d</p>",$mTime->format('H'));
    printf("<p> Minutos %d</p>",$mTime->format('i'));
    printf("<p> Segundos %d</p>",$mTime->format('s'));
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Formato no válido";
}
```

Salida:

```
<p> Hora 15</p>
<p> Minutos 30</p>
<p> Segundos 12</p>
```

Si pruebas el mismo código con una hora no válida, por ejemplo:

```
$hora = "150:30:12";
```

Tendrás como resultado:

```
Formato no válido
```

#### Recomendación

Te recomiendo que siempre uses la herramienta más adecuada para cada cosa. Si `$hora` es una hora, usa las herramientas del lenguaje para tratarla (en este caso la clase `DateTime`), que para eso existe.

Imaginemos que necesitas algo relativamente complejo con tu objeto como: *aumentar la hora dada en `N` horas y dividir ese intervalo de tiempo en períodos de `M` horas*.

Con tu objeto, lo harías así simplemente: haces una copia del objeto original (que sería la hora inicial), pero modificado en `N` horas, creas un rango de horas entre la hora inicial y la modificada, con intervalos en `M` horas. Eso será un período de tiempo que puedes recorrer con un bucle.

```
$hora = "15:30:12";
$mTime=new DateTime($hora);

$end = (clone $mTime)->add(new DateInterval("PT10H")); 
$interval = new DateInterval("PT1H");
$daterange = new DatePeriod($mTime, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("H:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
15:30:12
16:30:12
17:30:12
18:30:12
19:30:12
20:30:12
21:30:12
22:30:12
23:30:12
00:30:12
```

Answer (score 0):

`[0-24]` no significa *entre 0 y 24*. En cambio, coincide con **1** caracter, que puede ser 0, 1, 2 o 4.

Para tu pregunta en concreto, hay que cubrir todos los casos posibles para cada caracter en cada posición:

```
/^([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$/
```

- `[01]?\d` coincide con números entre 0 y 19 (el primer cero opcional).
- `|` es un `OR`
- `2[0-3]` coincide con números entre 20 y 23

Pero es muchísimo más fácil convertir el string en número y validarlo con `>` y `<`. No tiene sentido usar un regex en esto.

Comment: lo solucione asi: ```    if (preg_match("/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $hora,$partes)) {
 , no obstante, tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Está perfecto. `\d` es lo mismo que `[0-9]`